There is a natural map $\text{colim}_{\beta \in \alpha}\text{Mor}(A,B_{\beta})\rightarrow \text{Mor}(A,\text{colim}_{\beta \in \alpha}B_{\beta}) $
In the very beginning of 19 chapter in stack project I found this

Let $\{B_{\beta}\}_{\beta \in \alpha}$ be an inductive system (which means the index category is a filtering.) of objects in category $C$, then there is a natural map $$\text{colim}_{\beta \in \alpha}\text{Mor}(A,B_{\beta})\rightarrow \text{Mor}(A,\text{colim}_{\beta \in \alpha}B_{\beta})$$

I am confused how the elements of the left hand side look like. Johan gave a short proof. He commented that the left colimit is one of sets, which I assume he means $$\forall f\in \text{colim}_{\beta \in \alpha}\text{Mor}(A,B_{\beta}), \exists \beta \in \alpha \text{ such that, } f\in \text{Mor}(A,B_{\beta})$$

Did I understand this correctly? How could one show this?


"colimit of sets" means precisely what it says on the tin: It's a colimit in the category of sets. You can give a concrete description of these in terms of elements, which you should be able without much trouble in the literature.

To put this into a more general perspective: one can generalize this and we don't need anything beyond the definition of a colimit.
Let $F:\mathcal C \to \mathcal D$ be a functor and let $I$ be a (not necessarily filtered) small category and and assume that we are given a diagram $i:I \to \mathcal C$ such that the colimits $\operatorname{colim} i$ and $\operatorname{colim}(F \circ i)$ exist. Then there is always a natural map $\operatorname{colim}(F \circ i) \to F(\operatorname{colim}i)$.
This natural map is obtained by applying the universal property of a colimit. We have natural transformation $i \Rightarrow \Delta_{\operatorname{colim}i}$, where $\Delta_{X}$ denotes the constant functor with value $X$. This is just a fancy way of saying that we have a cocone with vertex $\operatorname{colim}i$. Now we compose this natural transformation with $F$ to obtain a natural transformation
$$F \circ i \Rightarrow F(\Delta_{\operatorname{colim}i})=\Delta_{F(\operatorname{colim}i)}$$
Which means that we have cocone over $F \circ i$ with vertex $F(\operatorname{colim}i)$. The universal property of the colimit gives us a unique compatible map $\operatorname{colim}(F \circ i) \to F(\operatorname{colim}i)$.
Apply this with $F=\mathrm{Mor}(A,-)$ to get the result in the question.
